# CHKDSK made partition a "GPT Protective Partition"? How to set it back?

Tags: ntfs, partition-recovery

**Background**

I stuck a 2TB drive in some Sata-to-USB3.0 enclosure and copied 1TB of data to it. It was 2,5 5300rpm drive, so it took nearly 20 hours. I am one of the paranoid types, so before I copied the data, I used TotalCommander to make sha256 checksums of everything I wanted to copy, I then ran a check on the copied data on the new USB drive. I have used two other pieces of the same enclosure for two other disks, 1TB though. Never had any trouble.

**Problem**

While verifying checksums, I observed a notification on Windows 10 action center with a red "X", that told me to check my filesystem. Didn't show which one, but I clicked it anyway. Nothing happened, so I ran eventviewer to see what happened. I saw three EventID 55 events pertaining to errors on my new volume, one of them saying that `„:$I30:$INDEX_ALLOCATION”` is corrupted, two other said corrupted file is `<can't determine file name>`. I stopped all operations on the volume and ran `chkdsk /F` on it, but because it complained that some other software is accessing the disk, I removed a drive letter using disk managemet utility. When I planned to add letter again to make chkdsk repair it, I suddenly saw all options greyed out and partition was displayed as `Healthy (GPT Protective Partition)`. This is type `EEh` according to [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_type).

The disk never was GPT. I still see an option `Convert to GPT disk` when right-clicking on it in Disk Management tool. Below is an output of `DETAIL DISK` and `DETAIL PARTITION` commands of `DISKPART`:

```
DISKPART> detail disk
ST2000LM003 HN-M201RAD
Disk ID: 08686B3E
Type   : RAID
Status : Online
Path   : 2
Target : 0
LUN ID : 0
Location Path : PCIROOT(0)#PCI(1700)#RAID(P02T00L00)
Current Read-only State : No
Read-only  : No
Boot Disk  : No
Pagefile Disk  : No
Hibernation File Disk  : No
Crashdump Disk  : No
Clustered Disk  : No
There are no volumes.

DISKPART> detail partition
Partition 1
Type  : EE
Hidden: Yes
Active: No
Offset in Bytes: 512
There is no volume associated with this partition.
```

This disk is not part of any raid, contrary to what is being displayed, it is currently connected to the SATA port directly on motherboard, maybe it shows as type RAID because controller is in RAID mode.

What I **think** happened (I have no way of verifying this) is that chkdsk was trying to repair volume in the background when I clicked this notification in action center, it must have set the ID of the partition to EEh, probably with the intention of resetting it back when it finished. When I set the drive letter to none, it must have errored-out and left it as stated.

**What I tried**

I was thinking of using DISKPART's SETID command to specify partition type of 07, however this does not work:

```
DISKPART> set id=07

DiskPart has encountered an error: The parameter is incorrect.
See the System Event Log for more information.
```

No event log messages are written to event log, it just doesn't work.

I think that setting this partition back to what it was will result in regaining access to files, and because I have one more of these disks which was formatted in the same way, I am convinced setting the partition ID to 07h will do the trick, only I can't seem to be able to do it. Below is data from my other-of-the-same harddisk.

```
DISKPART> detail disk

ST2000LM 003 HN-M201RAD SCSI Disk Device
Disk ID: BB31CF75
Type   : USB
Status : Online
Path   : 0
Target : 0
LUN ID : 0
Location Path : UNAVAILABLE
Current Read-only State : No
Read-only  : No
Boot Disk  : No
Pagefile Disk  : No
Hibernation File Disk  : No
Crashdump Disk  : No
Clustered Disk  : No

Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
* Volume 4     E   SMSNG1       NTFS   Partition   1863 GB  Healthy

DISKPART> detail partition

Partition 1
Type  : 07
Hidden: No
Active: No
Offset in Bytes: 1048576

  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
* Volume 4     E   SMSNG1       NTFS   Partition   1863 GB  Healthy

DISKPART>
```

If someone has experience in similar endeavor, please share your insight. I will not touch the drive for some time because I want to practice recovering from this situation. Upon recovery I will verify checksums of files and try to put the blame for the corruption that ticked off chkdsk either on the drive or the USB bridge.

**EDIT - drive data**

```
--------------- SeaTools for Windows v1.4.0.5 ---------------
2017-08-30 20:37:53
Model Number: 003 HN-M201RAD
Serial Number: S377J9GGA02406
Firmware Revision: 2BE1
Identify - Started 2017-08-30 20:37:53
Model Number: 003 HN-M201RAD
Serial Number: S377J9GGA02406
Firmware Revision: 2BE1
Drive Capacity: 2,00 TB / 1,82 TiB
Max LBA: 3907029167
Cache Size: ----
Lifetime Bytes Read: 3,54  GB
Lifetime Bytes Written: 545,50  MB
Power-On Hours: 4255
Annualized Workload Rate [ (Writes + Reads) * (8760 / POH) ]: 0 TB/yr
Drive Temperature (C/F): 29 / 84
WWN: 50004CF210CD3B3B
Sector size (Logical/Physical/Allignment): 512 / 4096 / 0
Signal Speed (Max/Negotiated): 6.0 / 6.0 Gb/s
Transport Supported: SATA 3.0
Rotation rate: 5400 RPM
Form factor: 2.5 inch
Specification Supported: ATA8-ACS
Encryption Support: Not Supported
Security Mode: Supported, Frozen
SMART: Enabled
Host Protected Area features: Enabled
Advanced Power Management: Enabled
Download Microcode: Segmented
```

**EDIT2 - sectors 0, 7 and 8**

[Sectors.txt](https://komprogram.pl/sectors.txt)

Comment: do you by any chance have a dump of sector 0, 1 and 2 of the disk? And, probably also sector 8 and 16, to make sure the disc is not affected by different sector size issues that can happen with switches between USB enclosures and direct SATA attachment. Chkdsk has no business changing the partition identifier, so that theory of yours doesn’t really sound probable. Also, try to find out sector size and number of sectors of the disc.

Comment: This disk was originally formatted in USB enclosure, and partition type changed to EEh without any swich to SATA at that time. Disk was online when this happened, only had drive letter removed by windows utility. I've connected this disk in the same enclosure to USB port of Windows 7 computer, but this showed that disk is UNINITIALIZED, so I thought I'll be sticking to Win10 until problem is resolved, so I did that.

Comment: Could not edit prevous comment - I added seatools report to the question and no, I never backed up any sectors of the drive.

Comment: I didn’t mean backed up sectors of the drive, but the current state. A simple dump of the current 16 or 17 sectors of the drive should give an indication whether something fishy is going on with the 4K-512b switcharoo or something else is happening. Windows typically only shows the EE partition if the remainder of the GPT is missing – or misplaced, which would be the case if the sector size doesn’t match.

Comment: Done, link is in second edit of the Q. After sector 8 theres no more data until well into the disk like I was fed up with scrolling.

Comment: So the disk was originally MBR format?

Comment: I don't know anymore, I formatted two disks one after another and the good one is MBR, this is why I wrote the disk was MBR. Honestly, I got confused after seeing sector 7.

Comment: Try [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk). It can find and restore partitions, if the filesystem itself is somewhat undamaged.

Comment: I tried testdisk and got info that ntfs is corrupted (from both testdisk and later chkdsk).

Comment: @Ro-ee further testing turned out to be bogus enclosure chipset and chkdsk, in fact, cannot be held responsible for changing partition identifier. Failing enclosure chipset is JMS567. Since then I purchased two other enclosures based on ASM1153E, which do not destroy data having the same HDDs in them.

Comment: JM = JMicron = only bad experiences...

Answer (score 0):

Since the disk is smaller than 2TB, I would stick to MBR and avoid the hassle with creating a GPT and bother with all the checksums, but instead change the last 64 bytes of sector 0 from

```
 0000000000432 | 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  3E 6B 68 08 04 D0 00 00 | 
 0000000000448 | 02 00 EE FE 7F FF 01 00  00 00 FF FF FF FF 00 00 | 
 0000000000464 | 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 | 
 0000000000480 | 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 | 
 0000000000496 | 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 55 AA |
```

to

```
 0000000000432 | 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  3E 6B 68 08 04 D0 00 00 | 
 0000000000448 | 02 00 07 FE 7F FF 00 08  00 00 00 80 E0 E8 00 00 | 
 0000000000464 | 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 | 
 0000000000480 | 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 | 
 0000000000496 | 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 55 AA |
```

That should do the trick.

I don’t really know why the GPT header is on sector 7 and the table is on sector 8, it should be either sector 7 and 15 *or* 1 and 2...

Comment: I edited per your instruction and the disk became RAW instead (in Disk Management). Chkdsk says NTFS boot sector is corrupt, unable to determine volume version and state so it aborted, doing nothing. By the way my second disk was just now corrupted too, it became RAW and also chkdisk says it can't do nothing with it. Guess my USB-to-SATA bridge can't deal with this type of disk. I now suspect the data was damaged thoroughout entire disks, both of them. I only performed read operations though.

Comment: please check if on sector 2048 of the disc (that’s the 00 08 from the line 448) you find the NTFS boot sector (it’s first few bytes contain the string NTFS... If that’s not the case, look for it in sector 16384. 
Also, if you find the NTFS boot sector, check if in bytes 11 and 12 of that sector (0xA, 0xB) there is written 00 02 or 00 10. If the latter is the case, the file system was formatted when connected as 4K, and a lot on the filesystem would have to be changed to have it work (the other way around – using a 512byte formatted NTFS on 4k – is flat out impossible)

Comment: There's NTFS string at sector 2048 and 0xA 0xB are 02 00, not 00 02. Sector 16384 contains file paths I recognize (e.g. files that were there), so it seems there was never boot sector there. From sector 2334 onwards string INDX can be found and recognizable file names in two-byte encoding. These are files I wrote to this disk yesterday. Anyway, since changing filesystem ID did not do the trick, I tried TestDisk on the just-corrupted-disk, which too resulted in nothing. And this time I know it was MBR. I will test USB enclosure some more and give up restoring. Not worth the time.